# Getting error when trying to access Sales > Orders in Magento 2 backend

Tags: admin, error, magento-2.0.5

I'm getting the following error when trying to access Sales > Orders in Magento 2 admin area. Any idea what the issue is?

```
Element 'listingToolbar': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( paging, filters, massaction, dataSource, columns, container ).
Line: 11

#0 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/DomMerger.php(395): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->createDomDocument('<?xml version="...')
#1 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(60): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->merge('<?xml version="...')
#2 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(47): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->readFiles(Array)
#3 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(101): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\FileCollector\AggregatedFileCollector), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Converter), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger))
#4 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#6 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/ReaderFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#7 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(247): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\ReaderFactory->create(Array)
#8 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(261): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->getReader('sales_order_gri...')
#9 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(169): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('sales_order_gri...')
#10 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(139): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('sales_order_gri...')
#11 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(125): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('sales_order_gri...', NULL, Array)
#12 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'sales_order_gri...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#13 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#14 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#15 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#16 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#17 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#19 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#20 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#21 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#22 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
#23 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Sales::...')
#24 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order.php(133): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Sales::...')
#25 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Index.php(17): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order->_initAction()
#26 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index->execute()
#27 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#28 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#31 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#32 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Sales\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#33 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#36 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Sales\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#37 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#40 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Sales\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#41 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#44 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#45 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#48 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#49 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#50 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#53 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#54 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#55 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#56 /home/americ23/public_html/www.mywebsite.com/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#57 {main}
```

Comment: What version of Magento do you use? Do you have any customizations in ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml file?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.0.5

Comment: Try cleaning var/generation and var/cache and refresh the page.

Comment: No luck...still getting error.

Comment: Please post your ui component XML

Comment: Where would that file be? Not too familiar with Magento 2.